# Webpage is load but can't get css file net::ERR_ABORTED 404 after upgraded to webpack5

Tags: reactjs, nginx, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

So the changes made before having this issue are upgrading to webpack 5 and changing AWS EC2 instances. So I checked Nginx config and webpack config files and didn't notice anything wrong. If open a new browser tab and enter the CSS file link, I am able to get the CSS file but occasionally need to fetch the 2nd or 3rd time to get the file. When the website loads, the CSS file seems not be able to loaded at the same time. In the HTMLWebpackPlugin, I have set the scriptLoading as 'blocking'. Any idea how to debug and fix this issue? Another questions, only webpack generated js and CSS file has load issue, the other files like flexbox.min.css has no issue to load.

Update: I downgraded to using webpack4 and this issue is gone. If anyone has an idea or knows any configuration regarding this, please please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Just to let you know, that this issue is fixed by stopping the instance and restarting it again.